# Developer mode will not work

Tags: magento2.3, developer-mode

I upgrade to 2.3.4 but the composer failed on one module.

After fixing this the developer site was missing the entire setup directory.
I have copied this from the production site but now I cannot get the developer site to work as both the dynamic and forced static deploy result in the developer mode missing files for example:

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://dev.romatech.co.uk/static/version1588063551/frontend/RTech/neo/en_GB/RTech_Contentful/images/arrow.svg): failed to open stream`

This looks like a failure to redirect.

I am using Nginx and have the .htaccess file in pub/static but no joy.

Can anybody help out with this?

Comment: check permissions

Comment: Thanks for this, the files are missing. On investigating further the dynamic deploy is deploying to en_US not en_GB. If I force to en_GB is works. How do I cause the dynamic deploy to go to en_GB or get how to redirect to to en_US instead of en_GB

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command:

```
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Comment: This will do a deploy of en_GB but this means that the development process is longer as the deploy takes times. I'm looking for a redirect for Nginx to use en_US or an automatic deploy of en_GB when in developer mode

Comment: If you want auto change to en_GB, you need to config in the admin. Please follow those steps: Change language of frontend : Store > Configuration > General > Locale Options. Change language of backend: System > All Users > Click Any User and change Interface Locale. Note: Please change to UK

Comment: These are both already set to en_GB. I'm not this suggestion would change the automatic deploy in developer mode either. This defaults to en_US which means that the Nginx redirect will not find deployed en_GB files. I either want to have Nginx redirect in developer mode find en_GB rather than en_US or have developer mode automatically deploy to en_US. All of this was working prior to the 2.3.4 failed update which removed the setup directory and other files.